# Click on link in iframe then perform jQuery action

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have this index page with an iframe on it. In the iframe I have some links like:

```
<a href="home.html" target="content">Who we are</a>
```

When I click on this link I would like to perform a jQuery action like sliding a div on the index page with this code.

```
$(window).load(function () {
$(".link_in_Iframe").click(function(){
$('.sliding_div_on_index_page').animate({'top': '-190px'}, 1000);
});
```

I know it is not possible to add/bind a click function to an iframe itself but could this be made possible with a link inside the iframe?

I managed the get the script working by replacing the click function by a hover function so basicly it works fine but I need to do this with a click function.

Comment: Sorry for that, did try some script before but did not work so asked a new question again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could

```
$('#iFrameID').contents().find('#linkID').click(function(){
$('.sliding_div_on_index_page').animate({'top': '-190px'}, 1000);
}); );
```

Replace `linkID` with the **ID** of the **link** in the iframe that you want to **trigger** the **click** and `iFrameID` with the **ID** of the **iframe** that contains the **link.**

For example, that code would work in the following HTML:

The **page** with the **iframe:**

```
<iframe id = 'iFrameID' src = 'yourPage.html' />
```

`yourPage.html` **or** `src` of the **`iframe:`**

```
<a id = 'linkID'>Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Man of Snow. Tryed this offline and it did notwork. Do I need to upload the html first?

the index and iframe page are of the same domain so this should be no problem.

Comment: @easyrider Can you post the page?  Also, does it work online?  Also, see what happens if the HTML is uploaded/check if the page isn't saved.  Also, do the IDs match?

Comment: I could post the page but it is very large so I showed a very small bit. No, your code did not work offline.

Comment: @easyrider I know it didnt work offline, but did it work online?

Comment: @easyrider Change `<a href="home.html" target="content">Who we are</a>` **to** `<a id="linkID" href="home.html" target="content">Who we are</a>`.  Also, make your iFrame's ID **`iFrameID`.**

Comment: @easyrider  It might be a problem with security to access `document`, use `try` and `catch` to see.

Comment: I use ID. I think I need to loadup the pages and see what happens.

Comment: @easyrider Right, use `window.load = function()`.

Comment: I use window.load = function() to. Maybe you are right about the security issue. I am going to put the html online in a few days and see. many thanks dough.

Comment: @easyrider You're probably right, you can see with `try` and `catch`.  So do you mind accepting my answer as a 'Thanks'?

Comment: I installed a local server. Put the HTML in the root and the script worked fine. Thanks again Man of Snow.